# Encoding in SHEF editor

Tags: java, html, swing, utf-8, internationalization

I'm trying to use [SHEF](http://shef.sourceforge.net/) as WYSIWYG editor. After I use `setText(String val)` in editor, every letter `ó` is replaced with it's html replacement: `&#243;`.

Even worse - after `getText()` every polish character gets replaced, not only `ó`.

I can work around the second problem, by de-encoding those characters, but I have no idea what to do, to make editor usable, and make it leave `ó` the way it was before.

I need help how to make SHEF work with UTF-8 or at least iso-8859-2 not iso-8859-0 (as I think it's the one it uses).